# how i can show the code in post that user need to show

Tags: wordpress, blogs, syntax-highlighting

i need to implemented add post system just like other blogging system such as wordpress.

i need a feature that user can put the code if they want and syntaxhighlighter show them in format.

how it is possible. what thing i need to use to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript based syntax highlighter such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/).